# neither/nor + plural

Tags: word-usage

> Buckingham Palace confirms to @NewshubNZ that neither Prince Philip or Queen Elizabeth **have** died.

I thought the plural **have** was a typo but I also found a similar  sentence on bbc.com

> Neither the Queen nor Prince Philip **have** a reputation for overindulging at mealtimes, according to royal historian Kate Williams.

Is it a kind of  majestic plural like royal we?